# Magento 2: remove menu links from customer account

Tags: magento2, menu

I want to remove these links `Downloadable products, My wishlist, Stored payment method, Billing agreement` form customer My Account page. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Add in layout file:
app/design/frontend/VendorName/themeName/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

```
        <!-- Store credit -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-customer-balance-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Downloadable product link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Subscription link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Billing agreement link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Product review link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- My credit card link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Account link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Account edit link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Address link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-address-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Orders link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Wish list link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Gift card link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-gift-card-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Order by SKU -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-checkout-sku-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Gift registry -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-giftregistry-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Reward points -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-reward-link" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: Hey, how did you get this information, is it in vendor somewhere? Otherwise I will be bookmarking the hell out of this answer XD

Answer (score 0):

Create a new module: i.e. `VendorName_ModuleName` (If you don't have already)

Add a layout file:

```
VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml
```

Remove links like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add new layout handle to one of places:

1. If creating new module:
   VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml
2. If creating new theme, 2 similar layout handles should be created to declare removal of each block separately:
   app/design/frontend/VendorName/themeName/Magento_Wishlist/layout/customer_account.xml
   (and similar layout for billing agreement module etc)

Layout handle content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for the above question. Added answer here for helping people.

I copied `customer_account.xml` file from `vendor` directory `vendor\magento\module-wishlist\view\frontend\layout\customer_account.xml` to my custom theme directory `app\design\frontend\VendorName\themeName\Magento_Wishlist\layout\customer_account.xml`.

Here is the code of my theme `customer_account.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
</body>
</page>
```